# What causes a java.lang.Error to be thrown with no details?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error, throwable

I occasionally come across `java.lang.Error` (just `Error`, not one of its subclasses) being thrown, with no apparent source and no detail message. [Example](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/40822-server-cant-start-with-forge/):

```
java.lang.Error
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:211)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190)
    (rest of stack trace omitted)
```

This is [LoadController.java:211](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/blob/11d237f5f2817bf08acee1271406763cba256304/src/main/java/net/minecraftforge/fml/common/LoadController.java#L211):

```
FMLLog.log(modId, Level.TRACE, "Sending event %s to mod %s", stateEvent.getEventType(), modId);
```

Another [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/32alrv/vanilla_server_crashing_help/):

```
java.lang.Error
    at java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(ArrayList.java:317)
    at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:300)
    (rest of stack trace omitted)
```

This is [ArrayList.java:317](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u20/jdk/file/f5d77a430a29/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l317):

```
if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
```

(Links go to full stack traces and sources.) All circumstances I can think of that result in an `Error` actually result in a more specific subclass of it, and/or a message with details. What could cause just an `Error` to be thrown in these places?

Comment: What is being returned by your Mod's modid() method when the first error occurs?

Comment: Custom loggers can potentially reformat the stack trace exception that will get printed into console or file. Or the program can catch the actual exception and rethrow `Error`.

Comment: @tsolakp To my knowledge, Minecraft Forge's crash reporter is accurately showing the thrown exceptions. Cases like these are relatively rare; it usually gives useful and correct exceptions. Also, if the program were re- throwing as an Error, wouldn't the stack trace point to a "throw new Error()" statement?

Comment: @Michael Krause it looks like the first example happened with just Forge and no other mods, so I'm guessing it was one of "Minecraft", "Forge", or "FML". Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself. Minecraft has a server watchdog thread (`net/minecraft/server/dedicated/ServerHangWatchdog.java` in the MCP source), which monitors the main server thread and causes this to happen if it takes too long to run a single tick. The code that looked like it was throwing the Error in this stack trace was in fact completely unrelated to it.